# cordova is installed but not starting up

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, npm, terminal

I installed node.js 8.9.3 and a successfully installed with following message

```
This package has installed:   
   •    Node.js v8.9.3 to /usr/local/bin/node
   •    npm v5.5.1 to /usr/local/bin/npm 

Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.
```

I run following command in terminal mac ...

```
$  $PATH
```

And i get following return..

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory
```

**Q1. What does that last line mean? No such file or directory?**

.. after that i run following commands..

```
$ which node
And following is response
/usr/local/bin/node
```

and similar for

```
$ which npm
And following is response
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

I think everything is fine till now..

Now i installed ...cordova typing..

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

It is installed and the next lines after completing installation i see ..

```
/Volumes/macHDD/Users/samz/.npm-packages/bin/cordova -> /Volumes/macHDD/Users/samz/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
+ cordova@8.0.0
updated 1 package in 27.977s
```

**Q2. is it successfully installed? if so.. why is this not as global?**

when i test typing

```
$ which cordova
```

terminal says nothing..  I also tested typing 
$ cordova -version or $ cordova --version .. or even if i type

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

I am "slapped" by terminal :(

```
-bash: cordova: command not found
```

...

in the last night. i was successful in installing cordova, and I created 2 test apps.. i was able edit them, even I run those apps on android emulator and on my ios device+emulator. 
during building/preparing one of my app, I tried to create one more app project through a seperate terminal instance. And there I saw .. like no cordova.

I terminated first instance where cordova was working.. and reopened terminal to test if this is an issue.. and yes.. it was .. I could never work on cordova again.

Can somebody tell me what is the issue. ?.
it's very irritating now.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this is resolved..

I reinstalled node, npm, java, cordova (several times), but nothing could resolve. 
and today .. i upgraded node9.3.0 from node8.9.3.. but still the same errors.

Now i had..

```
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:colors muhammadfarooqi$ node --version
v9.3.0
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:colors muhammadfarooqi$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:colors muhammadfarooqi$ npm -version
5.5.1
Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:colors muhammadfarooqi$ cordova -version
8.0.0
```

i was about to kill myself.. but i found something on the internet with some other issue.. and i run the same command.

```
sudo rm -rf node_modules
sudo npm install
```

and then i installed cordova. 
and wow... cordova is there :)

i dont' know what exactly was the solution .. I dont' know what this line of code did.. I know the above line removed node_modules and 2nd lines installed npm.. and now I am seeing cordova is running.

Please somebody, if my solution works for anybody, kindly comment. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is because you typed just `$PATH`. This is then expanded to its value, and then the shell attempts to execute it, which is obviously not possible.

To check your current PATH, type `echo $PATH` instead.

Your second issue is probably due to a partial configuration to use a user-specific global package directory.

By default, packages are installed in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, with symlinks for binaries in `/usr/local/bin`, which requires root access (`sudo`). You have at one point configured npm to install in a different directory (~/.npm-packages), but did not include the bin sub-directory in your PATH.

So you need to either finalise the configuration (see https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions for details), or revert to using `/usr/local`.